# Cannot startx on Debian after some changes

Tags: xorg, gnome, kde, startx, kdm

I installed and removed some packages and changed some settings on my Debian server. After reboot I can't run x11vnc to remote it using VNC.
Now when I run startx, the result is:

```
 no screens found
```

X -configure:

```
 Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
```

x11vnc -auth guess gives me:

```
 failed for display='unset'
 since we are root, retrying with FD_XDM=1
 failed for display='unset'
```

I don't know what my server configurations is but my fresh installation of Debian worked nice. Now I installed KDM, KDE, Gnome, Xorg, etc. to get the graphical screen but I don't know what some of them are.

How can I fix my system without reinstalling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed every package related to Desktop and Window environment with aptitude and installed  x-window-system, xfce4, gdm3, vnc4server.